# Skype and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, skype, ubuntu-14.04

I remove my old skype and try install new but have error how to install skype

now I have

```
sudo apt-get install skype
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype : Depends: skype-bin but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

I try

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
apt-get install gdebi
wget download.skype.com/linux/skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
sudo gdebi skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
```

and have

```
Cannot install 'libqtwebkit4:i386'
```

Comment: Nice to see Russian text with `ё` for a change.

Comment: what does the error mean

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/215298/unable-to-install-skype-on-64bit-ubuntu

Comment: Check this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/488053/how-to-install-skype-4-3) to install in command line.

Comment: Other way you can download deb file from the Skype [website](https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/) and install.

Comment: Yes, I try download and install from oficial web sity, but not help, still have this error

Comment: update question